# Display javascript result in a pageblocktable

Tags: javascript, pageblock

I am making a Ajax call to a REST API and parsing the response and maintaining the parsed values in a delimited string. I want to display the same string in the pageblocktable without taking the control to the controller. I want everything to be in Javascript.

VFPage:

JS:

```
function()
{
$.ajax(
{
     url : weblink,
     success : function(result)
     {
         var resultData = result.content.resultData[i]
         //assume resultData is a delimited string
document.getElementById('pgad1:frm:ADValues').value = resultData ;
     }
}
}
```

PageBlockTable:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!ADAddrList}" id="ADValues"/>
<td width="50%" valign="top">
            <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" id="addresspb">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AddrLst}" var="r" id="records" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(AddrLst))}">
                    <apex:column >
                        <input type="radio" name="SelectAddress" value="{!r.fulladdress}" onclick="changeValue(this, '{!$Component.RadioButtonValue}');" /> 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="City" Value="{!r.locality}" />
                    <apex:column headerValue="State/Province" Value="{!r.province}" />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Zip Code/Postal Code" Value="{!r.postcd}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>     
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:actionFunction name="SelectedAddress" action="{!SelectedAddress}" rerender="Address" status="myStatus"/>
            <apex:inputHidden value="{!AddrSelectedValue}" id="RadioButtonValue" /> 
            <apex:actionFunction name="Validate" action="{!Validate}" rerender="Address,addresspb" status="myStatus"/>
        </td>
```

At present I am passing the string to controller using actionfunction and then displaying it on the page.
But, I want to know how can we display the string in the pageblocktable without calling the controller.

Please help!

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: How closely do you want the result to follow the format of the standard SFDC UI?

Comment: it may not be as close as Std SFDCUI. But a HTML look where in, i can display the resultset in a page like:  displaying a list which has data for Locality, Country, Province

Comment: Please can you share an example from a few rows of your data?

Comment: @Prashant, I've added text formatting around your visualforce code. You should always do this when you post, but especially so for markup as SE will *interpret* your markup instead of *display* it unless it knows it is code.

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to stay out of the controller? REST call...jQuery...seems like a lot of work to do what you could have done in a few minutes with a simple custom controller and standard VF tags. Unless you roll your own and drop pageblock table, my guess is that you'll need to use a page inspector to understand the underlying HTML and then manually manipulate what you find there. make sure you use id's for all levels of hierarchy so you can control the DOM id's of all elements.

Comment: I will take care next time Peter about the formatting. I have a REST API from where I will get the desired data and show on the VF page. But, REST API's can be called via JS (browser side), which will avoid a server hit for my each call to the API. so, if I want to take advantage of the REST API call via browser script then, I thought lets do all the processing of the data (parsing, displaying) at browser side. I know it can be done easily via custom controller, but i dont want to use controller :)

Comment: MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:MOUNTAIN VIEW;CALIFORNIA;94043:

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to manipulate. But I would recommend assembling this on the server-side over mocking it in JS by hand. You could combine JS Remoting, Dynamic Components and Page.getContent

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Localities">
    <script>
      var headers = ['Locality', 'Country', 'Province'];

      var data = [
        ['Warrawee', 'Australia', 'New South Wales'],
        ['Sheffield', 'United Kingdom', 'Yorkshire'],
        ['Anderlecht', 'Belgium', 'The French Part']
      ];

      /**
       * Convert 1D array to table cells
       * @return {HTMLTableRowElement}
       */
      Array.prototype.toTrTd = function() {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.className = 'dataRow';
        this.map(function(item) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
          tr.appendChild(td);
        });
        return tr;
      };

      /**
       * Convert 1D array to table headers
       * @return {HTMLTableRowElement}
       */
      Array.prototype.toTrTh = function() {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.className = 'headerRow';
        this.map(function(item) {
          var th = document.createElement('th');
          th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
          tr.appendChild(th);
        });
        return tr;
      };

      /**
       * Convert 2D array to page block table
       * @param {String[]} headers
       * @return {HTMLTableElement}
       */
      Array.prototype.toPbTable = function(headers) {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.border = 0;
        table.cellSpacing = 0;
        table.cellPadding = 0;
        table.className = 'list';

        //table headers
        table.appendChild(headers.toTrTh());

        //table rows
        this.map(function(item) {
        var tr = item.toTrTd();
          table.appendChild(tr);
        });

        return table;
      };

      var table = data.toPbTable(headers);
      document.write(table.outerHTML);
    </script>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u! I tried to use the code in my script with the output I receive. But it isnt working.